# Proguard removes Anonymous class in Anonymous class in Java

Tags: java, android, proguard, anonymous-class

I have a issue that Proguard is not working when you declare a anonymous class within a anonymous class. This is what it looks like in a basic example:

```
public class Class1 {
  public void function1 (){
     new Class2(){
        @Override
        public void function2(){
          new Class3(){
            @Override
            public void function3(){
              // do something
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

During a gradle build script proguard is being executed. Now i get the following error:

```
 my.package.Class1$2$1: can't find enclosing method 'void function2()' in program class my.package.Class1$2
```

If I change the code to just have 1 "level" of anonymous classes proguard is finishing without errors. This works:

```
public class Class1 {
  public void function1 (){
      Class3 class3Instance = new Class3(){
            @Override
            public void function3(){
              // do something
            }
      }
      new Class2(){
        @Override
        public void function2(){
           //do something with class3Instance  
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The project is a android project, though as far as I know that should not matter.

I tried all different kind of `-keep` rules for `Class1`, but nothing worked. Is this not supported by Proguard or do I have to add a rule to get it to work?

**UPDATE 1:**

As requested the structure if the interface used for the anonymous classes. 
The interface for `Class2` is defined as follows:

```
public class Class2IntefaceEnclosingClass {
    public interface Class2 {
        void function2();
    }
}
```

The interface for `Class3` is slightly different:

```
public interface Class3IntefaceEnclosingInterface {
    interface Class3 {
        void function3();
    }
}
```

*Note:* I can not change the layout of the interfaces since they are provided by android.

Comment: Class2 must be extending some class (say Foo). You can have keep clause some thing like this. -keep class * extends Foo {public void function2;}

Comment: Class2 implements a interface. Which is in turn defined as a inner interface of a interface (It is from Android).  I tried: `-keep class * extends package.OuterInterface { *; }` and `-keep class * extends package.OuterInterface.InnerInterface { *; }` and `-keep class * extends package.OuterInterface$InnerInterface { *; }`. I also activated `-keepattributes InnerClasses`. No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Could you please share the exact structure of the interface and its usage, to understand the nesting. (Exact fully qualified names are not expected)

Comment: I updated my original post with the requested information.

Comment: Please try adding below keep options. `-keep interface your.package.Class2IntefaceEnclosingClass$Class2 {*;}` and `-keep interface your.package.Class3IntefaceEnclosingInterface$Class3 { *;}`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [@Keep](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Keep.html) annotation above function1(), function2() and function3().

```
public class Class1 {
  @Keep
  public void function1 (){
     new Class2(){
        @Keep
        @Override
        public void function2(){
          new Class3(){
            @Keep
            @Override
            public void function3(){
              // do something
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```